# Problems with encoding in IntellijIDEA on Windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I launch my program, it crashes on the line 
`String[] words = tdElement.text().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]", " ").split(" ");`

with the following exception: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 16` 
`[^a-zA-ZР°-СЏРђ-РЇ ]`

This "tdElement" contains both English and Russian letters. When there is no Russian letters in the "tdElement", everything works fine. I tried to go to **"Settings" -> "File Encodings"** and set the "Global Encoding", "Project Encoding" and "Default encoding for properties files" fields to UTF-8, but it didn`t work. Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps the equivalent regex `"[^a-zA-Z\u0430-\u044F\u0410-\u042F ]"` will work?

Comment: That did work! Thanks a lot